# Rest web services and jquery ajax method i used i got error

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services

I got the below error
XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://localhost/assessment/api.php/useradd`. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

I use the below code please help me to fix the issue

```
var serviceURL = "`http://localhost/assessment/api.php/`";
$("#useraddButtonId").click(function() {
    $('#userFrmId').submit();
});    
$('#userFrmId').submit(function(){  //alert('hi');  
    var postData = $(this).serialize();
    //postData="username=test";
     // postData = { username: "John", email: "Boston" };
     //alert(postData);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: postData,
        url: serviceURL+'useradd',
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
            if(data.response == 1) {
                console.log(data);
                alert("User added Successfully");
                window.localStorage.setItem('form_active','#addrFrmId'); // store local storage
                window.location.href='index.html';
            }else{
                console.log(data);              
                alert(data.response);

            }   
        },
        error: function(data){alert(data);
            console.log(data);
            alert('There was an error adding your comment');
        }
    });

    return false;
});


api.php

function useradd_post(){
        $this->load->model('user_model');
        $datas['username']=$this->input->post('username');
        $datas['email']=$this->input->post('email');
        $datas['phone']=$this->input->post('phone');
        $this->user = new User();
            $ret = $this->user->web_user_insert($datas);

            if($ret) {
                $this->response($ret, 200); // 200 being the HTTP response code
            } else {
                $this->response(NULL, 404);
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript ajax is limited to making ajax calls within the same domain.  In your case, it looks like that is your intention.  It might make sense to change the service URL to be relative... the code will assume same domain.  Use /assessment/api.php/useradd.

If that's not the case for you, it's still fixable.  Your service will need to be changed to handle the OPTIONS request that is being fired before the POST to check for the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.  It needs to return that header as part of the response.  I don't know enough about PHP to help you out there.  Looks like there's some info about that here...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Server-Side_Access_Control